# How to make a button for reset

Tags: button

I have a form with one button to submit value entered text boxes:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="gallery.php">
............

.....

...   

<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
<a href="gallery.php">Reset</a>
```

My problem is with the reset. How can I make it to be a button also?

Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
<input type="button" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" onclick="window.location.href='gallery.php'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Reset" />

$('#button').click(function(){
window.location.href = "gallery.php";
});
```

If you don't want to use jquery then :

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'gallery.php';" value="Reset" />
```